# mysql use FOREIGN KEY on two columns

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have the following tables:

TABLE1

```
| id | nr | name | ...
```

TABLE2

```
| id | nr | prod | ...
```

TABLE3

```
| id | nr | prod | act | data | publ | ...
```

PROD

```
| id | id_prod | prod | name | ...


TABLE2.nr FOREIGN KEY TABLE1.nr DELETE RESTRICT UPDATE CASCADE

TABLE3.nr FOREIGN KEY TABLE1.nr DELETE RESTRICT UPDATE CASCADE

TABLE2.prod FOREIGN KEY PROD.id_prod DELETE RESTRICT UPDATE CASCADE

TABLE3.prod FOREIGN KEY TABLE2.prod DELETE RESTRICT UPDATE CASCADE
```

The problem is between `TABLE2` and `TABLE3`

Suppose I have

TABLE2

```
| id | nr | prod | ...
  1   301   1001
  2   301   1005
  3   301   2098
  4   305   1005
  5   305   2099
```

TABLE3

```
| id | nr | prod | act | data | publ | ...
  1   301   1005   1     ...    ...    ...
  2   301   1001   NULL  ...    ...    ...
  3   305   2099   1     ...    ...    ...
  4   305   2098   1     ...    ...    ...
```

Now suppose I want to `DELETE FROM TABLE2 WHERE id = 4`.

Mysql returns an error because there is a FOREIGN KEY between TABLE2.prod and TABLE3.prod.

But in fact, I'm not touching the data of the object with `nr = 301` which also has an entry `301 1005` in TABLE3.

How can I solve this problem? Is it possible to ADD a FOREIGN KEY between 2 columns?

I want to prevent deleting from TABLE2 data that is present in TABLE3 but comparing columns `nr AND prod` not only `nr OR prod` (by now I have the problem with prod).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why should T3's prod foreign key point to T2? It should point to Prod instead.

ID #1 in T3 points to 1005 which points to that entry in T2 you are trying to delete. That violates the foreign key you set when you try to delete that T2 entry.

Comment: T2 defines which prod's has this nr . T1 defines the global characteristics of the nr. and T3 the prices. So if I point T3.prod to prod directly I've not a control to the nr. products, because in T3 there are many rows with the same product and different prices, but only one is active .

Comment: there should be only one golden source of identifiers. it looks like T1 should be the prime candidate for nr and Prod for prod. you might want to re-look at whether your foreign keys are fulfilling your requirements.

Comment: Prod is used also in other tables outside t1,2,3. T1 is the main table for nr. One nr one row. T2 has the prod's of the nr of T1. Each nr has multiple prods. Each prod has a price and T3 has the price of each prod of each nr with an historical archive. In fact the column act defines which price is active now. How can I redefine?

Comment: Then it sounds like my original suggestion holds. T3 should reference Prod for prod and T1 for nr. As long as each entry's prod and nr values are valid (existing in Prod and T1), then your data integrity is maintained.

Comment: How can I control which prod's are active for each nr? They're not the same for each nr, and the user on the cms should be able to activate and deactivate a prod for a nr and so on

Comment: You probably need to extend your solution with some sort of status column that you can query and update to.